# How to use customized Window in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, window

I am using jsp for my web Application.

Here i wanted to open a window as popup on click event.

But , I wanted to it looks like ,

[image]

Then i Google it and found some answers from web links like w3school
And i have tried as ,

[image]

### " The window from Microsoft System window "

also the code as ,

```
window.open(event.url+'?title='+event.title, 'gcalevent',
'resizable = no ,fullscreen = no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,titlebar=no,width=700,height=600,top=30,left=250');
```

But i wanted as shown 1st image,

So please help me to do this , it could be in any format in jsp as ,

javascript or java or ajax or any extentions(jar , script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't depend on the server-side technology. You need a javascript library to display dialog pseudo-windows.

Check [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) Dialog for example.

Comment: Can some give me some examples of customized Dialogs...please...Thanks it is really good..

Comment: the page I linked has an example